# PHP Doctrine: What happened to orm-fixtures?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, fixtures

When I run the command:

```
composer require --dev orm-fixtures
```

I get the following:

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package orm-fixtures.

  Did you mean one of these?
      shake/database
      shake/scaffolding
      its-mieger/lara-db-ext
      scr-be/arthur-doctrine-fixtures-bundle
```

What happened to the package "orm-fixtures"? Are there any substitutes?

https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html

Comment: The Symfony flex server has been known to 'hiccup' on occasion.  I just made a new project and the fixtures installed just fine.  Unless you are behind some sort of firewall or something then just try again.

Comment: I just tried again and am still getting the error.  I'm not seeing the package in Packagist.  I am using Docker to run the composer command.

Comment: Hmmm.  Does Docker run 'symfony new ...' as well?  All I can say is that the bundle installs fine from a regular console window.  So it still exists.  The flex server is different than the packigist server.  Not sure if it uses the same ports or not.

Comment: By the way, adding symfony and docker tags to your question might help.

Comment: I think composer is now (2022) using *https://packagist.org/?query=orm-fixtures* as the url to ask for the package: this can be seen using *composer -vvv*, and packagist does not know anything about symfony aliases (which are indicated in the recipe file)... I don't know if this incorrect composer behaviour is related to flex gone serverless (https://symfony.com/blog/symfony-flex-is-going-serverless) around *September 22, 2021*, or some other change ‍♀️

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
composer require --dev orm-fixtures
```

Use:

```
composer require --dev doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle
```

This command also should automatically enable this bundle.